# MySQL IF in WHERE condition Based On SELECT Column

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple (actually I'm simplifying the real case) SQL command :

```
SELECT Username, Message
FROM Mail
WHERE DeleteBySender = '0'
LIMIT 1
```

but for some reason, I have special condition, that is : 
**IF Mail.Username = 'johndoe'** then the WHERE clause **is not** `DeleteBySender = '0'` anymore, **but** `DeleteByReceiver = '0'`.

in short, how to make dynamic WHERE clause based on Mail.Username result?

can it be done with single SQL command? because if not, in my real case, it will cause PHP scripting more complex.

**UPDATE : what I really expect, in plain English :
if Mail.Username NOT johndoe, SQL command will be like this :

```
SELECT Username, Message
FROM Mail
WHERE DeleteBySender = '0'
LIMIT 1
```

but if Mail.Username IS johndoe, SQL command will be like this :

```
SELECT Username, Message
FROM Mail
WHERE DeleteByReceiver = '0'
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Username, 
    Message
FROM Mail
WHERE (IF(Username='johndoe',DeleteByReceiver = 0,DeleteBySender =0))
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 5):

*A solution* in SQL utilizing an `OR` clause to break up your logic as follows:

```
SELECT Username, Message
FROM Mail
WHERE (Username != 'johndoe' AND DeleteBySender = '0')
OR (Username = 'johndoe' AND DeleteByReceiver = '0')
LIMIT 1
```

**Note:** The `LIMIT 1` is concerning. Without knowing your dataset, this may return more than one result. You need to test.

Comment: This'll also select rows where `Username = 'johndoe'` and `DeleteByReceiver <> '0'`, but `DeleteBySender = '0'`. I don't think that's what the OP wants. You should change the first part of the WHERE clause to `(Username <> 'johndoe' AND DeleteBySender = '0')`

Comment: @Joseph Silber, good point. See update. And thanks for commenting with your down vote.

Comment: Not my DV. The OP's needs (which were since updated) hadn't been expressed clearly enough to invalidate this answer, so I didn't downvote. Thought a comment would be more constructive.

Comment: @Joseph Silber, fair enough. I imagine they had the same point as you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Username, Message
FROM Mail
WHERE (Username = 'johndoe' AND DeleteByReceiver='0') OR DeleteBySender = '0'
LIMIT 1
```